# How can I achieve sync functionality in Dropbox?

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I want to have a sync functionality between my computer and Dropbox app. Whenever app files get updated, my local folder should also update.

Is there any way to achieve this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, Dropbox has a developer API and a .NET SDK available to download.

For file synchronization you can checkout the documentation for Files [here](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/N_Dropbox_Api_Files.htm).